# Changing CSS class elements values for a given class

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change the gradient which is changing the color stop parameter percentage based on some value from outside. How can I change it?

e.g. `#ff2828 15%, #fff728 15%`. By changing both these values I could control color.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<title>beep</title>
<style>
.backgroungDiv{
height:31px;
width:600px;
position:absolute;
background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3232 0%, #ff2828 15%, #fff728 15%, #fff728 54%, #28ff33 81%, #8fff89 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff3232), color-stop(15%,#ff2828), color-stop(15%,#fff728), color-stop(54%,#fff728), color-stop(81%,#28ff33), color-stop(100%,#8fff89)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 15%,#fff728 15%,#fff728 54%,#28ff33 81%,#8fff89 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 15%,#fff728 15%,#fff728 54%,#28ff33 81%,#8fff89 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 15%,#fff728 15%,#fff728 54%,#28ff33 81%,#8fff89 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 15%,#fff728 15%,#fff728 54%,#28ff33 81%,#8fff89 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#8fff89',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

clip: rect(0px 500px 600px 0px); /* here 2nd argument given on base of SNR calcuation*/
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function SoundOn()
{
 if(document.getElementById('chk').checked ==false)
 {
    document.getElementById('demo').volume=0;
 }
 else
 {  
    document.getElementById('demo').volume=.3;
    document.getElementById('demo').play();
 }
}

function SoundOnIe()
{
 if(document.getElementById('chk-ie').checked ==false)
 {
    document.getElementById('demo1').volume="-10000";
 }
 else
 {  
    document.getElementById('demo1').volume="-3000";
    document.getElementById('demo1').play();
 }
}
-->
</script>
<body>
<!--[IF IE]>
<BGSOUND id="demo1" loop=-1 volume="-10000" src="beep-9.wav" >
<input id="chk" onClick="SoundOnIe()" type="checkbox">
<![endif]-->
<![IF !IE]>
<audio id="demo" loop=-1 volume=0 src="beep-9.wav" ></audio>
<input id="chk" onClick="SoundOn()" type="checkbox">
            <div id="empty" style="background-color:#cccccc;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;height:31px;width:595px;"> 
            <div id="SNR_bar_graph" class="backgroungDiv" style="text-align:center;">16.1</div>
            </div>
<![endif]>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; what are you trying to do?

Comment: Here in css class backgroungDiv , i need to change the color stop ranges.-moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3232 0%, #ff2828 15%, #fff728 15%, ...)if I could cahnge the #ff2828 and #fff728 values ie 15% to 20% , i could change the gradient .That what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include jQuery in your script header and then try something like this:

```
function changeBGGradient(){
var a = "#ff3232 0%";
var b = "#ff2828 25%";
var c = "#fff728 50%";
var d = "#28ff33 75%";
var e = "#8fff89 100%";

myDiv.css({"background":"-moz-linear-gradient(left,"+a+","+b+","+c+","+d+","+e+")"});
myDiv.css({"background":"-webkit-linear-gradient(left,"+a+","+b+","+c+","+d+","+e+")"});
myDiv.css({"background":"-ms-linear-gradient(left,"+a+","+b+","+c+","+d+","+e+")"});    
myDiv.css({"background":"linear-gradient(left,"+a+","+b+","+c+","+d+","+e+")"});
}
```

Obviously you can send through a,b,c,d,e as parameters and change then like you need.

Comment: Can I use javascript alone to do this ?

Comment: Yes without jQuery - I think you could do this: myDiv.style.background = "linear-gradient(left,"+a+","+b+","+c+","+d+","+e+")"

Comment: so before that: var myDiv = document.getElementById('empty');